# NextJS and Vercel CNAME for www domain

Tags: web, dns, next.js, vercel

I have finished my web page in NextJS, pushed to GitHub and from there deployed the project via Vercel. I have set up custom domain DNS - added the required A record - and set in Vercel to use this domain. Everything works well, just a small thing going wrong. Whenever I try to access my domain like this example.com or https://example.com there are no issues, only problem appears when I try to access it like [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - with the "www".

What would be the solution for this? When using ReactJS with GitHub pages I had to add CNAME into my domain DNS settings, do I have to do something similar now?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to add the "www" subdomain to your project as well.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. When I tried to add "www" subdomain Vercel clearly guided me to finish the set up. Now it is all working. Thanks again!